# Unable to save report that includes a datasource of Microsoft SQL Azure type

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have install SSRS in azure using the following instructions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449661.aspx) and all seems to work fine, however when I create a report in report builder 2014 (in this case empty) that includes a Microsoft SQL Azure datasource type I am unable to save the report and get the following error message (even though when I test connection it succeeds).

"The report definition was saved, but one or more errors occurred while setting the report properties"

Reports with standard sql datasources work fine.

I have also tried creating the report using Visual Studio 2013 and get a similar error message.

I have tried this using SQL 2012 and SQL 2014 and get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was running SQL Web edition, you require at least standard to save different types of datasources.